# Move cursor to the beginning of a designmode iframe

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor

Is it possible to move the caret to the very beginning (right before first element) of a designmode IFRAME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function to do that. Pass in a reference to the `<iframe>` element.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aLP26/

Code:

```
function moveCursorToStart(iframeEl) {
    var win = iframeEl.contentWindow || iframeEl.contentDocument.defaultView;
    var doc = win.document;
    if (win.getSelection && doc.createRange) {
        var sel = win.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(doc.body);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (doc.selection && doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, neat! Do you have any thorough guide on these ranges?

Comment: @Jauzsika: Not really. I've written a lot of answers on this kind of thing on SO and I've documented Range and Selection methods for my Rangy library (http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). I hope to write a longer guide some time. MDN is not bad: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:range and https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:Selection. TextRange docs on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have struggle for half of a day against the issue how to move cursor to the end of iframe when it get focus() event. I just modified your code collapse(ture) to collapse(false), everything run as my except. I have also looked your rangy liberary, I think it's a bit heavy(if <10k could be great), and you can provide a few of demos, something like quick start.